# Reach manhood or reach to manhood?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, sentence-construction

1) When he reaches to manhood, he will visit England.
**OR**
2) When he reaches manhood, he will visit England.

Which of the two is correct?

Comment: The second is correct.  It seems like an answer should be able to explain why, which I can't, so I'll just comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is yet another "preposition usage" context where ***usage has changed over time***. NGrams doesn't have enough written instances of unquestionably *abstract* "states that can be reached" (such as ***manhood, maturity***) to show on a chart, but I think ***heaven*** is close enough, if we think of it as a "state of being" rather than a "physical location" that can be *traveled* to...

[image]

As that chart clearly shows, a couple of centuries ago you were as likely to *reach **to** heaven* as to *reach heaven*. I know some people will say those two usage *mean* different things (with ***to***, it's ***strive*** to get there - maybe unsuccessfully; without, it's *successfully get there*). But I don't think that's the whole explanation, and there are plenty of (mostly, older) written instances of [*reach(ed) to maturity*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22reached+to+maturity%22) in Google Books to show that including the preposition is/was far from unknown.

---

I'd say the general trend has been for English to use *more* prepositions in contexts where they help disambiguate between possible intended meanings, but to *discard* prepositions where disambiguation is irrelevant. In the context of ***to reach***, the two possible meanings (*strive towards*, or *actually arrive*) can be 100% disambiguated by including ***for*** or not...

> 1: *People like him will never reach the stars* (He'll never get there)
>    2: *People like him will never reach **for** the stars* (He'll never even ***try*** to get there)
>    3: *People like him will never reach **to** the stars* (Uncommon today, but could carry *either* sense)

...so we don't need to bother with ***to***.

---

TL;DR: It used to be more common to include the preposition for contexts like OP's example, but times have changed. I wouldn't say including ***to*** is "ungrammatical", but it's an *optional* usage that's fallen out of fashion.

Comment: [Here's another NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28%28reach+to+the+top%29+*+10%29%2Creach+the+top&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28%28reach%20to%20the%20top%29%20%2A%2010%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creach%20the%20top%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C((reach%20to%20the%20top)%20*%2010)%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creach%20the%20top%3B%2Cc0) showing that ***reach the top*** and ***reach to the top*** were about equally common until 1900, but since then the prepositionless version has become at least **5 times** more common.

Answer (score 2):

*Reach to X* is used if X is something you can touch or physically do.  If X is a status, *to* isn't used (because it's something you *become*, not something you "move" to).

So it's *reach manhood*, but it would be *reach to other desk, reach to the back*, etc.

Comment: *reach to other desk???*

Answer (score 2):

You don’t say reaches to manhood in that case, you say reaches manhood. The subject is not physically nor is he mentally reaching for manhood. He is not trying to grab manhood. He is waiting for manhood. So, the correct one is reach. When he reaches manhood, he will visit England.